# Degree of a monomial in Macaulay2?

Tags: polynomials, macaulay2

Instead of defining a monomial ordering in Macaulay2, I would like to get the vector of degrees of a monomial. For example, if I define

```
R=QQ[x,y]
p=x^2*y^5
```

I would like to get, from `p`, the vector `(2,5)` giving the corresponding degrees. How can I do this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a multigrading.

```
i1 : QQ[x,y, Degrees => {{0,1},{1,0}}];

i2 : degree(x^2*y^5)

o2 : {2,5}
```

See also the [documentation](https://macaulay2.com/doc/Macaulay2-1.20/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_degree_lp__Ring__Element_rp.html).

Comment: I mean, that works, but it also feels overly complicated for a common task like this.. Thanks though.